# Joining Three tables in SQL with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I've three tables in SQL named : Table1, Table2 and Table3

my tables are have this columns table1 : Name,adress,email and Table2: Name,seller,country and Table3 : Country,amount,Booleen

what I'm looking to do is join table1 to table2 by '***name***' column than join the result of that to table3 by using '***country***' column creating an end table with sum of '***amount***' column if '***Booleen***' column equals 'True' and Groupby Name at the end.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Yes but getting results far from what i expect ...

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output in your question. Also add the SQL you are using, and how its results are not what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for -

```
select t1.name, sum(amount)
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
join table3 t3 on t2.country = t3.country
where booleen = 'True'
group by t1.name;
```

Comment: Hello, I'm getting an error saying 'Unknown column 't2.country' in on clause do you know why ?

Comment: can you make sure you have columns in these tables as you mentioned in your question?

Comment: table1 : Name,adress,email and Table2: Name,seller,country and Table3 : Country,amount,Booleen

Comment: yes they are exactly the same names..

Comment: I have corrected the SQL. Pls check now

Comment: It's working thank you so much :)

Comment: Last question I want to show other columns values like country  ... is it possible ?

Comment: yes you can. Please open a question with as much details as you can. When you ask a question of SQL, you must provide sample records and expected output.